# Electron and macOS: how to customize the 'About <app>' display panel that pops up when user clicks the 'About <app>' menuItem?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

When writing an Electron app, the macOS build provides an "About " menu item as the first item of the first menu[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R66re.png). When this is clicked, a small panel pops up displaying app name, version, and copyright if available[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttip6.png).

**How to customize the contents rendered in the panel?**

The [Electron menuItem role docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item#roles) only mentions:

```
 `about` - Map to the `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel` action.
```

The [apple docs on `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428724-orderfrontstandardaboutpanel#parameters) don't provide any insight.

See screenshots, including an example of a customized display panel (via GIMP):

[image: about app menuItem from macOS electron app]

[image: about app display panel from macOS electron app]

[image: customized about gimp display panel on macOS]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not nearly as pretty as what you want, but if you just want to customize the simple built-in About Panel for macOS, Electron does let you customize the text.

You simply call [app.setAboutPanelOptions](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetaboutpaneloptionsoptions)

```
  /*
    Here's how the "About" dialog is displayed: (applies to macOS only)

    <app icon>
    <applicationName>
    <applicationVersion> (<version>)
    <credits>
    <copyright>
   */
  app.setAboutPanelOptions({
    applicationName: "Name", 
    applicationVersion: "App Version",
    version: "Version",
    credits: "Credits",
    copyright: "Copyright"
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

I use ['About This App' Window for Electron Apps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/about-window) lib. Simple, easy to implement.

Apparently it is possible to completely customize the content through the `use_inner_html` option but I haven't had a need to do that so can't speak to how well it works.